# alternate row colors for only some columns

Tags: tables, formatting, color

I'd like alternating row colors for only specific columns (and in a perfect world, also only a subset of rows), with a table using multirow and multicolumn.  I've found that putting `\rowcolor{COLOR}` starting with the target column works (shown below)... but it raises a `misplaced \noalign` error.

I'm using TexShop (3.6.1) on OSX, with pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)

Is there a better way to do this?  Or a way to get the above method to not raise an error?

[image]

```
[![\documentclass\[6pt, oneside\]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage\[cm\]{fullpage}

\usepackage\[table\]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\mc}\[2\]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\newcommand{\mr}\[2\]{\multirow{#1}{*}{#2}}


\begin{document}


    \begin{table}\centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc ccc lccc@{}}
    \toprule
                            &                   & \mc{4}{Background}                                        &                   &               &               &           \\
    \mr{2}{One Column}      & \mr{2}{Two Column}& \mc{2}{Amp}                   & \mc{2}{Spectrum}          & \mr{2}{Subset}    & Stuff         & \mc{2}{\mr{2}{Fraction}}  \\ 
                            &                   & $1$           & $0.1$         & $1$       & $0.1$         &                   & All (Coal)    & \mc{2}{}                  \\\midrule
    \mr{8}{Stuff}           & \mr{4}{0.6}       & \mr{4}{3.7}   & \mr{4}{15}    & \mr{4}{-3}& \mr{4}{-0.59} & \rowcolor{blue!20}All             & 29  (2.7)     & $ 1875/ 9270$ & $(0.20)$  \\
                            &                   &               &               &           &               & \rowcolor{blue!30}$\mu>0.2$       & 26  (2.2)     & $ 1225/ 4759$ & $(0.26)$  \\
                            &                   &               &               &           &               & \rowcolor{blue!20}$M>10^8$        & 17  (4.0)     & $ 608 / 2610$ & $(0.23)$  \\
                            &                   &               &               &           &               & \rowcolor{blue!30}$M>10^8$,$\mu>0.2$& 6.9 (3.3)   & $ 214 /  478$ & $(0.45)$  \\

                            & \mr{4}{1.0}       & \mr{4}{4.7}   & \mr{4}{17}    & \mr{4}{-6}& \mr{4}{-0.38} & \rowcolor{blue!10}All             & 7.7 (1.2)     & $ 4634/ 9270$ & $(0.50)$  \\
                            &                   &               &               &           &               & \rowcolor{blue!20}$\mu>0.2$       & 4.8 (1.0)     & $ 2900/ 4759$ & $(0.61)$  \\
                            &                   &               &               &           &               & \rowcolor{blue!10}$M>10^8$,       & 4.9 (0.79)    & $ 1422/ 2610$ & $(0.54)$  \\
                            &                   &               &               &           &               & \rowcolor{blue!20}$M>10^8$,$\mu>0.2$& 0.35 (0.35) & $  472/  478$ & $(0.99)$  \\

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:params}
    \end{table}



\end{document}][1]][1]
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

[image]

To obtain above image I first clean-up your code. It contain bunch of errors caused by wrong use options (they had to be inside `[...]` and not in math environment `\[...\]`). Then to each cell, which you like to have colored, wrote `\cellcolor{<selected color>}`. This is only way (for which I know) that you have only part row in desired color. To simplify this task (since all colors ara based on blue), I defined new command:

```
\newcommand{\CC}[1]{\cellcolor{blue!#1}}
```

and (after lot of work) I rewrote your MWE into:

```
\documentclass[6pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\newcommand{\mr}[2]{\multirow{#1}{*}{#2}}
\newcommand{\CC}[1]{\cellcolor{blue!#1}}
    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*{6}{c} lccc}
    \toprule
        &                       & \mc{4}{Background}&                   &               &               &
        \\
One     & Two   & \mc{2}{Amp}   & \mc{2}{Spectrum}  & \mr{2}{Subset}    & Stuff
        & \mc{2}{\mr{2}{Fraction}}
        \\
Column  & Column    & $1$       & $0.1$ & $1$   & $0.1$                 
        &           & All (Coal)    & \mc{2}{}                  
        \\ \midrule
\mr{8}{Stuff}         
    & \mr{4}{0.6}   & \mr{4}{3.7}           & \mr{4}{15}   &  \mr{4}{-3}
    & \mr{4}{-0.59}     
    & \CC{20} All   & \CC{20} 29 (2.7)      & \CC{20} $1875/9270$   
    & \CC{20} $(0.20)$  \\
    &   &   &   &   &                     
    & \CC{30}$\mu>0.2$  & \CC{30} 26 (2.2)  & \CC{30}$ 1225/4759$
    & \CC{30}$(0.26)$  \\
    &   &   &   &   &  
    & \CC{20}  $M>10^8$ & \CC{20} 17 (4.0)  & \CC{20} $608/2610$
    & \CC{20} $(0.23)$  \\
    &   &   &   &   &
    & \CC{30}$M>10^8$, $\mu>0.2$    
                        & \CC{30}6.9 (3.3)  & \CC{30}$214/478$  
    & \CC{30}$(0.45)$   \\
  & \mr{4}{1.0}     & \mr{4}{4.7}   & \mr{4}{17}
  & \mr{4}{-6}      & \mr{4}{-0.38} 
  & \CC{10} All     & \CC{10}7.7 (1.2)      & \CC{10}$4634/9270$
  & \CC{10}$(0.50)$  \\
    &   &   &   &   &
    &               & 4.8 (1.0)     & $ 2900/4759$          
    & $(0.61)$      \\
    &   &   &   &   &  
    & \CC{10}$M>10^8$, & \CC{10}4.9 (0.79)& \CC{10}$1422/2610$
    & \CC{10}$(0.54)$  \\
    &   &   &   &   &  
    & \CC{20}$M>10^8$,$\mu>0.2$      & \CC{20}0.35 (0.35) & \CC{20}$472/478$     & \CC{20}$(0.99)$  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{huh, finally my wonderful table :-)}
    \label{tab:params}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of `nicemtrix` (v 6.0 of 2021-08-10) has a command `\rowlistcolors` available in the `\CodeBefore` dedicated to that kind of problem.

```
\documentclass[6pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}ccccw{c}{7mm}w{c}{1cm}lccc}
\CodeBefore
 \rowlistcolors{4}{blue!05,blue!10,blue!20,blue!30}[restart,cols={7-10}]
\Body 
\toprule
        & & \Block{1-4}{Background}& & & & 
        \\
One     & Two   & \Block{1-2}{Amp}&  & \Block{1-2}{Spectrum} &  & \Block{2-1}{Subset}  &  Stuff
        & \Block{2-2}{Fraction}
        \\
Column  & Column    & $1$       & $0.1$ & $1$   & $0.1$                 
        &           & All (Coal)    & 
        \\ \midrule
\Block{8-1}{Stuff}         
    & \Block{4-1}{$0.6$}   & \Block{4-1}{$3.7$}           & \Block{4-1}{$15$}   &  \Block{4-1}{$-3$}
    & \Block{4-1}{$-0.59$}     
    &  All   &  29 (2.7)      &  $1875/9270$   
    &  $(0.20)$  \\
    &   &   &   &   &                     
    & $\mu>0.2$  &  26 (2.2)  & $ 1225/4759$
    & $(0.26)$  \\
    &   &   &   &   &  
    &   $M>10^8$ &  17 (4.0)  &  $608/2610$
    &  $(0.23)$  \\
    &   &   &   &   &
    & $M>10^8$, $\mu>0.2$    
                        & 6.9 (3.3)  & $214/478$  
    & $(0.45)$   \\
  & \Block{4-1}{$1.0$}     & \Block{4-1}{$4.7$}   & \Block{4-1}{$17$}
  & \Block{4-1}{$-6$}      & \Block{4-1}{$-0.38$} 
  &  All     & 7.7 (1.2)      & $4634/9270$
  & $(0.50)$  \\
    &   &   &   &   &
    &               & 4.8 (1.0)     & $ 2900/4759$          
    & $(0.61)$      \\
    &   &   &   &   &  
    & $M>10^8$, & 4.9 (0.79)& $1422/2610$
    & $(0.54)$  \\
    &   &   &   &   &  
    & $M>10^8$, $\mu>0.2$      & 0.35 (0.35) & $472/478$     & $(0.99)$  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\caption{huh, finally my wonderful table :-)}
    \label{tab:params}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: The minus sign is it in math-mode o is it a usual `-`?

Comment: @Sebastiano: I don't know. I have used the code of the OP.

Comment: Sorry...I have not read well the image of the user....:-( excuse me very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this effect by alternating row and column color like following:

```
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|g|g|g|g|g|g|g}
\hline
\rowcolor{white}
&col1 &col2 &col3 &col4 & col5 &col6 &col7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}
row1& \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra \\
row2& \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra \\
\rowcolor{white}
row3& \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra & \ra \\
...
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Source: [highlight table rows/columns](http://texblog.org/2011/04/19/highlight-table-rowscolumns-with-color/)

Comment: -1: first, you haven't included the necessary packages, command defs, etc for this to be directly usable.  second, after looking through the link, this doesn't address the question at all.  it only addresses alternative row/column colors --- instead of restricting to particular columns.

Comment: Yep, I just post it because I had the same issue and I found this solution so I though it would be good to share it with other people. I'm not a latex expert so I don't know which packages should be included to use. It if you know hem feel free to edit the answer. Any way the code works and does what the question is asking for.